# Celery and pyinstaller

Tags: python, redis, celery, celery-task

I want to have a Celery Worker (with Redis as the broker and backend) which will recieve tasks from several remote Celery producers (through the use ".send_task").

I'm trying to package the producer side into a single *.exe with pyinstaller. The idea is to run the *.exe which will send a task to the remote Celery worker.

Here's the "producer" code:

```py
from celery import Celery

def main():
    print('Sending Task')
    #celery_app.send_task('add',args=(2,2))
    celery=Celery('redis://:password@redis_server:6379')
    celery.send_task('tasks.add',(2,2))


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I then compile the code into a single file with pyinstaller. Unfortunately I'm running into an exception when trying to run the executable. I'm getting the following error:

```
Sending Task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sendtask.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "sendtask.py", line 6, in main
  File "celery\app\base.py", line 291, in __init__
  File "celery\app\base.py", line 291, in <listcomp>
  File "kombu\utils\imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery.fixups'
[5588] Failed to execute script 'sendtask' due to unhandled exception!
```

- Python v.3.8.10-64
- Pyinstaller v. 4.5.1

Anyone know if it's possible to have a python script compiled into an executable send tasks to a remote Celery worker?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
José

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with pyinstaller==4.8, celery==5.2.3 and python 3.9.7.

On my project i solved by adding explicity **hidden-import** requirements on the pyinstaller command line.

```
pyinstaller.exe --hidden-import celery.fixups --hidden-import celery.fixups.django myprogram.py
```

I guess it's due to an improper dependecy analysis from Pyinstaller, it seems it's common to manually explicit some deps when deploying project with such kind of tools.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue.
But it was more complicated as I was compiling a celery worker file using PyInstaller.

It doesn't work even after I put some of the celery sub-modules on `--hidden-import` option.

Finally I found these sub-modules have to be explicitly imported on the main file. So PyInstaller knows what modules to collect.

#### Version I use

PyInstaller: v4.2

Python: 3.9.8

#### celery_worker.py

```py
from celery import Celery

# PyInstaller friendly imports --start--
import celery.app.amqp
import celery.app.log
import celery.worker.autoscale
import celery.worker.components
import celery.bin
import celery.utils
import celery.utils.dispatch
import celery.contrib.testing
import celery.utils.static
import celery.concurrency.prefork
import celery.app.events
import celery.events.state
import celery.app.control
import celery.backends.redis
import celery.backends
import celery.backends.database
import celery.worker
import celery.worker.consumer
import celery.app
import celery.loaders
import celery.security
import celery.fixups
import celery.concurrency
import celery.events
import celery.contrib
import celery.apps
import celery
import celery.fixups
import celery.fixups.django
import celery.apps.worker
import celery.worker.strategy
import kombu.transport.redis
import sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator               
import sqlalchemy.ext.baked
# PyInstaller friendly imports --end--


def init_celery_app():
    celery_app = Celery(
        "my-celery-app",
        broker="redis://localhost:6379",
        result_backend="redis://localhost:6379",
    )

    return celery_app


celery_app = init_celery_app()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    celery_app.worker_main(
        argv=[
            "worker",
            "--loglevel=info",
            "--queues=my_queue",
        ]
    )
```

#### PyInstaller Compile command

Somehow I have to exclude `django` and `tkinter` otherwise the build would fail.

Here is the command I use:

```bash
/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.sh -F \
    --exclude-module=tkinter \
    --exclude-module=django \
    celery_worker.py
```